# changing the contents of a file applying different conditions

Tags: python

I am trying to do some changes in the contents of an input file. The input file I have looks like the following:

```
18800000 20400000 pau
20400000 21300000 aa
21300000 22500000 p
22500000 23200000 l
23200000 24000000 ay
24000000 25000000 k
25000000 26500000 pau
```

This file is a transcription of an audio file. The first number denotes the start time and the next one denotes the end time. Then the alphabets denote the sound.

The change I have to make is, there are a few sounds which is made of two different sounds ie there are some diphthongs too. So these diphthongs have to be split into the two sounds. In the example above the diphthong is 'ay'. It is made of 'ao' and 'ih'.
What happens here is, the duration of 'ay' which is 24000000 - 232000000 = 8 is distributed into these two sounds. The result will be,

```
23200000 24000000 ay
```

changes to

```
23200000 236000000 ao
23600000 240000000 ih
```

I have attempted to write a pseudo code which looks rubbish.

```
def test(transcriptionFile) :
    with open("transcriptions.txt", "r+") as tFile :
        for line in tFile :
            if 3rd_item = ay
                duration = (2nd_item[1] - 1st_item[2]) / 2
                delete the line
                tFile.write(1st_item, 1st_item + d, ao)
                tfile.write(1st_item + d, 1st_item, ih) # next line

if__name__ == "__main__" :
    test("transcriptions.txt")
```

Thank you.

With the suggestions I was given I changed the code to the following. It is still not correct.

```
def test(transcriptionFile) :
    with open("transcriptions.txt", "r") as tFile :
        inp = tFile.readlines()

    outp = []
    for ln in inp :
        start, end, sound = ln.strip()
        if sound == ay :
            duration = (end - start) / 2
            ln.delete
            start = start  
            end = start + duration
            sound = ao
            outp.append(ln)
            start = start + duration # next line 
            end = start
            sound = ih 
            outp.append(ln)

    with open("transcriptions.txt", "w") as tFile:
        tFile.writelines(outp)

__name__ == "__main__"
test("transcriptions.txt")
```

Comment: Once you get your code running, you need to test if __name__ == "__main__" and only execute test if this is true

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following script should do what you want:

```
import sys

def main(src, dest):
    with open(dest, 'w') as output:
        with open(src) as source:
            for line in source:
                try:
                    start, end, sound = line.split()
                except ValueError:
                    continue
                if sound == 'ay':
                    start = int(start)
                    end = int(end)
                    offset = (end - start) // 2
                    output.write('%s %s ao\n' % (start, start + offset))
                    output.write('%s %s ih\n' % (start + offset, end))
                else:
                    output.write(line)

if __name__ == "__main__":

    main(*sys.argv[1:])
```

Output:

```
18800000 20400000 pau
20400000 21300000 aa
21300000 22500000 p
22500000 23200000 l
23200000 23600000 ao
23600000 24000000 ih
24000000 25000000 k
25000000 26500000 pau
```

Answer (score 2):

Editing a text file in-place is pretty hard. Your best options are:

1. Write the program as a Unix [filter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filter_%28Unix%29), i.e. produce the new file on `sys.stdout` and put it in place with external tools
2. Read in the whole file, then construct the new file in memory and write it out.

A program following the second line of thought would look like:

```
# read transcriptions.txt into a list of lines
with open("transcriptions.txt", "r") as tFile:
    inp = tFile.readlines()

# do processing and build a new list of lines
outp = []
for ln in inp:
    if not to_be_deleted(ln):
        outp.append(transform(ln))

# now overwrite transcriptions.txt
with open("transcriptions.txt", "w") as tFile:
    tFile.writelines(outp)
```

It would be even better if you'd write the processing bit as a list comprehension:

```
outp = [transform(ln) for ln in inp
                      if not to_be_deleted(ln)]
```

Comment: The filter approach is definitely much better. Easier to debug and you get the power of the rest of the UNIX text manipulation tools.

Comment: How can I refer to the items of each line?

Comment: @zingy: do `start, end, sound = ln.split()`.

Comment: It doesn't show any syntax error when I run the code. And I guess I have followed your framework. The if statement is different, I didn't check for "if not to_be_deleted(ln)". I should check if sound = 'pau' so that necessary changes can be made right?

Comment: @zingy: sorry, I was mistaken, it's not a syntax error. Yes, you should check for `sound == 'pau'`.

Comment: @larsmans Thanks but it turns out that I don't have to deal with 'pau' anymore. Its the part of my research and now I have found another solution so 'pau' should not be deleted. But yes the next condition has to be solved as I can't avoid that. So I will edit the question and try to solve the second part.

Comment: When I ran the code earlier there wasn't any syntax error though the code is still right. But After I deleted the first part and ran the code with only the 2nd part then now its showing an error on line "start, end, sound = ln.strip()" as ValueError: too many values to unpack

Comment: @zingy: I'm not writing your program for you. Please post a new question if you still have problems, or use your google-fu.